# Automate a python script through strings?

Tags: python

let say that thoses python objects below are **locked** we just cannot change the code, all we can is writing right after it. i know it's aweful. but let say that we are forced to work with this.

```
Name01 = "Dorian"
Name02 = "Tom"
Name04 = "Jerry"
Name03 = "Jessica"
#let say that there's 99 of them
```

**How to print the name of each and single one of them (99) witouth repetition ?**

from my noob perspective. the ideal way to resolve this case witouth repetition is using the same logic that we have with strings.

Because name => **Name+index**
so it can be really easy to iterate with them.

so somewhat a code that work in the same logic of the totally fictive one below:

```
for i in range (1,100):
    print(Name+f"{i:02d}")
```

```
for i in range (1,100):
     string_v_of_obj = "Name" + str(f"{i:02d}")
     print(func_transform_string_to_code(string_v_of_obj))
```

maybe something like that is possible.

```
for python_object in script_objects:
    if Name in python_object:
       print(python_object)
```

Comment: @KlausD.how is that helping the OP? Did you read his description? He said that he cannot change this part of code, so what's your solution? To rewrite all variables in a list by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `eval()`

```
>>> Name01 = "Dorian"
>>> Name02 = "Tom"
>>> Name04 = "Jerry"
>>> Name03 = "Jessica"
>>> for i in range(1, 100):
...   print(eval('Name%02d'%i))
... 
Dorian
Tom
Jessica
Jerry
```

incase if you are using 3.7+ you can go with `f string`

```
f"Name{i:02d}"
```

Comment: thank you ! i didn't knew this eval() function, thanks for this answer !

Answer (score 2):

This could do the trick:

```
Name01 = "Dorian"
Name02 = "Tom"
Name04 = "Jerry"
Name03 = "Jessica"

vars = locals().copy()
for i in vars:
    if 'Name' in i:
        print((i, eval(i)))
```

alternative in one line:

```
Name01 = "Dorian"
Name02 = "Tom"
Name04 = "Jerry"
Name03 = "Jessica"

print([(i, eval(i)) for i in locals().copy() if "Name" in i])
```

Comment: You are printing extra data (the OP just asked to print names) and you didn't take into account possible duplicates as per requirement

Comment: @Pitto I think he has the critical thinking to get only the values he needs, I just added it to help him. Also how  can a variable has a duplicate please explain that to me?

Comment: Please check my solution below

Comment: Ok I did see your code and I see why you said that I did not take into account about duplicates but I don't think the OP by 'with no repetition' meant to exclude variables with the same value but  to use a loop instead of using the same code again and again.

Comment: Oh I see...
Yes, it can also be read in that way.
Maybe more clarity would be helpful, @DB3D

Answer (score 0):

You can access the global variables through `globals()` or if you want the local variables with `locals()`. They are stored in a `dict`. So

```
for i in range (1,100):
    print(locals()[f"Name{i:02d}"])
```

should do what you want.

Comment: That would easily break if the range or names are not exactly right, it may be better to check for the common part.

Comment: `locals()` is the correct thought but you need to get a `copy()` of that while it's a dynamic object and you would have problems using the object itself.

Comment: No, you would not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exec:

```
Name01 = "Dorian"
Name02 = "Tom"
Name04 = "Jerry"
Name03 = "Jessica"
for i in range(1,5):
    num = f"{i:02d}" # python3.6+
    num = "{0:02d}".format(i) # python 3.x
    num = "%02d"%i # python 2
    exec('print(Name'+num+')')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this code, as per requirement, you will just print names without printing duplicates:

```
Name01 = "Dorian"
Name02 = "Tom"
Name03 = "Tom"
Name04 = "Jerry"
Name05 = "Jessica"
Name06 = "Jessica"

vars = locals().copy()

names = []

for variable in vars:
    # This will make sure that we are only
    # using variables having 'Name' in their names
    if 'Name' in variable: 
        # Getting the variable's value
        value = eval(variable)
        # If the value is not duplicate
        if value not in names:
            # Append it to our final names list
            names.append(value)

for name in names:
    print (name)
```

Output

```
Dorian
Tom
Jessica
Jerry
```

Explanation

> The locals() function returns a dictionary containing the variables
>   defined in the local namespace. Calling locals() in the global
>   namespace is same as calling globals() and returns a dictionary
>   representing the global namespace of the module.